# Which area of the Capital Wasteland has the most Deathclaws?

Tags: fallout-3

As my experience level in Fallout 3 gets higher, I want to hunt a lot more deathclaws. Is there a part of the map that is just lousy with deathclaws?

Comment: I *think* it's Deathclaw Sanctuary in the South... west(?) corner of the map, but I'm not sure. There *is* a bobblehead and a named weapon there though! =D

Comment: @Fluttershy You mean a "unique" variant of a weapon :D

Comment: @Retrosaur Yeah. One of those unique weapons with a name! =D

Answer (score 8):

The two most populated areas full of [Deathclaws](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Deathclaw) would be [Old Olney](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Old_Olney) and the [Deathclaw Sanctuary](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Deathclaw_Sanctuary).

Answer (score 0):

The deathclaws in the sanctuary do not respawn. You must complete waters of life to get more than 1-2 to spawn near the exterior entrance.

Old Olney and the area near the alien crash site/power station are dependable locations prior to completing the quest. A one time spawn of 4-5 will also occur near the raid shack/bethesda ruins before becoming randomized creatures.